# PHP value not between two numbers

Tags: php

Right now I have the following code:

```
if ($costOne <> $costTwo) {}
```

and I'd like to change this to

```
if ($costOne is not within the range of $costTwo - .0001 and $costTwo + .0001) {}
```

I've tried writing this a few different ways but I'm not doing something right....  can someone provide me the correct syntax to express this?

Comment: Just have two conditions in your if statement. One that checks the low value, ne for the high

Comment: what does mean by ur second condition

Comment: Usually, with float checking: `if(abs($first - $second) < $allowed_difference))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically had it:

```
((($costTwo - 0.0001) <= $costOne) && ($costOne <= ($costTwo + 0.0001)))
```

Or, alternatively

```
(abs($costOne - $costTwo) <= 0.0001)
```

Comment: I like the abs way then it's possible and useful :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
$lowerbounds = $costOne - .0001;
$higherbounds = $costOne + .0001;
if($costOne < $lowerbounds || $costOne > $higherbounds){ ....
```